# R sort column that contains "Width x Height"

Tags: r

I have a data table that contains Width and Height. I want to print the frequency of each Width and Height in a bar chart. I managed to do this, but I want the barchart to be sorted on Width x Height starting on low to hight dimensions.

This is what I have:

[image]

The correct sorting will be something like this:
[image]

My code:

```
# Library
library(ggplot2)

# 1. Read data
df = read.csv2(text = "ID;Width;Height
1;255;298
2;600;900
3;333;459
4;333;459
5;800;574
6;512;768
7;768;1024
8;768;1024
9;800;574
10;512;768
11;640;1136
12;1200;1600
13;255;298
14;600;900
15;600;900
16;255;298
17;512;768
18;600;900
19;255;298
20;600;900
21;768;1024
22;255;298
23;640;1136
24;640;1136
25;333;459
26;255;340
27;1200;1600
28;640;1136
29;255;298
30;255;298")

# 2. Add width and height together as Dimensions
df_dimensions <- paste(df$Width, "x", df$Height)
df_dimensions <- as.data.frame(table(df_dimensions))
colnames(df_dimensions)[which(names(df_dimensions) == "df_dimensions")] <- "Dimensions" # Set column name 
df_dimensions <- df_dimensions[order(df_dimensions$Dimensions),] # order
df_dimensions

# 3. Plot bar chart
ggplot(df_dimensions, aes(x = Dimensions, y = Freq)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
          theme_classic() +
  coord_flip() +
          ggtitle("Dimensions (Width x Height)") +
          xlab("Dimensions") + 
          ylab("Frequency") +
          geom_text(aes(label = Freq), hjust = -0.5)
```

Comment: why is 255 * 340 before 255 * 298?

Comment: I just did the sorting in Paint, it should not be before.

Comment: So your arrangement is incorrect?

Comment: I updated the image of sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df = read.csv2(text = "ID;Width;Height
1;255;298
2;600;900
3;333;459
4;333;459
5;800;574
6;512;768
7;768;1024
8;768;1024
9;800;574
10;512;768
11;640;1136
12;1200;1600
13;255;298
14;600;900
15;600;900
16;255;298
17;512;768
18;600;900
19;255;298
20;600;900
21;768;1024
22;255;298
23;640;1136
24;640;1136
25;333;459
26;255;340
27;1200;1600
28;640;1136
29;255;298
30;255;298")

df %>% 
  mutate(dimensions = paste(Width, "x ", Height)) %>% 
  add_count(dimensions, name = "Freq") %>%
  arrange(Width, Height) %>% 
  mutate(labelpos = Freq + 0.2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(dimensions) %>% fct_rev())) + 
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(x="Dimensions", 
       y="Frequency") +
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Freq), y = labelpos), size=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- subset(data.frame(table(df[-1])), Freq >0)

with(a[seq(nrow(a), 1), ],
       barplot(Freq, horiz = TRUE, names.arg = paste(Width, Height, sep = 'x')))
```

[image]

Comment: Can it be done with ggplot2 similiar to what I have in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a column with the area:

```
dims <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df_dimensions$df_dimensions), ' x '))), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
df_dimensions$area <- dims[,1]*dims[,2]
```

Then plot

```
ggplot(df_dimensions, aes(x = reorder(Dimensions,-area), y = Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme_classic() +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Dimensions (Width x Height)") +
  xlab("Dimensions") + 
  ylab("Frequency") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), hjust = -0.5)
```